# How can I detect when objects of a Django model are added/deleted?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

When adding or removing objects of `Foo` type I need to do the same calculation. How can I detect the adding/deleting of objects for `Foo` model? For example:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self):
        #do some processing

    def delete(self):
        #do some processing
```

**Can I avoid the code duplication in these two methods?**

Using signals you can implement it like

```
from django.db import models 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete

class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    ...

def foo_handler(sender, **kwargs):    
    #do some processing 

post_save.connect(foo_handler, sender=Foo)
post_delete.connect(foo_handler, sender=Foo)
```

Comment: No.  Why?  There is no duplication.  This is perfect.  And very simple.  And what everyone expects.  What don't you like about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Django's signals to call a particular function before or after a model is saved or deleted (and also at other times, if need be). Check out the relevant documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

If you override the model methods, your `delete()` will not be invoked when deleting object in bulk from a queryset (see [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods)).

You may connect several signals to the same method using `signal.connect`.

Comment: Good point, the bulk methods from manager often issue a single query and not fire signals at all.

Comment: It'd be great if this answer had an example to complete it; right now it's just a set of links a user has to visit to get the answer, instead of containing the answer. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers